# SSRS get list of AD groups for current user but #error

Tags: reporting-services

I have a piece of code that allows you to retrieve the AD groups of a user in a SSRS report.
However, I get an #error in my report locally but also when I run it via the SSRS portal. I think it has something to do with additional permissions? Does anyone know how to get it to work?

```
Public Function GetUserMembership(ByVal strUser As String ) As String
Dim groups As String
Try
 Dim obEntry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=aw,DC=com")
 Dim srch As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(obEntry, "(sAMAccountName=" & strUser & ")")
 Dim res As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult = srch.FindOne()
 If res IsNot Nothing Then
 Dim obUser As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(res.Path)
 ' Invoke Groups method.
 Dim obGroups As Object = obUser.Invoke("Groups")
 For Each ob As Object In DirectCast(obGroups, System.Collections.IEnumerable)
  ' Create object for each group.
  Dim obGpEntry As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ob)
  groups = groups + obGpEntry.Name + ";"
 Next
 End If
Catch ex As Exception
 groups = ""
End Try
Return groups
End Function
```

To use it in the report:

```
=Code.GetUserMembership(Split(User!UserUD, "\")(1))
```

Additional, I found an assembly reference is required to use the class System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry. In my case I found the .dll (DirectoryServices) at the following location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f00f6bc-15dc-4ca4-b0c7-99cabf5abd90/ssrs-2008-r2-how-to-get-the-logged-user-group-information?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: What's the error say? Is the path to the DLL the same on the server?

Comment: @aduguid that's what it says in the SSRS report, just #error
DLL is on the same server yes.